# How to check if a Class method has been called only once with JEST

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, jestjs

#### Question:

How should I check if the `Service.init()` method has been called only once ?

###### Error

```
expect(received).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(expected)

    Matcher error: received value must be a mock or spy function

    Received has type:  object
    Received has value: {"constructor": [Function Statistics], "init": [Function init]}

      13 |     const Module3 = Service
      14 |
    > 15 |     expect(Service).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1)
         |                     ^
      16 |   })
      17 |
```

#### Code

index.spec.js:

```
  it('should initialized a class instance only once', async () => {
    const Service = require('./index')
    jest.mock('./index')

    const Module1 = Service
    const Module2 = Service
    const Module3 = Service

    expect(Service).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1)
  })
```

and basically a class code:

```
class Statistics {
  constructor () {
    console.log(' Constructor')
    this.init()
  }

  async init () {
    // Wait 500ms
    console.log(' Initializing')
    await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve('ok'), 500))
    console.log(' Initialization complete')
  }
}

module.exports = new Statistics()
```

Comment: why do I get negative feedback ? Would be nice to leave a comment if somone is not happy about the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not calling the function before checking it. An example from the documentation - Use `.toHaveBeenCalledTimes` to ensure that a mock function got called the exact number of times.

For example, let's say you have a drinkEach(drink, Array) function that takes a drink function and applies it to array of passed beverages. You might want to check that the drink function was called an exact number of times. You can do that with this test suite:

```
test('drinkEach drinks each drink', () => {
  const drink = jest.fn();
  drinkEach(drink, ['lemon', 'octopus']); // calling the function and checking it
  expect(drink).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(2);
});
```

In your test spec, creating the instance will be enough to call init:

```
  it('should initialized a class instance only once', async () => {
    const Service = require('./index');
    jest.mock('./index')

    const Module1 = Service
    const Module2 = Service
    const Module3 = Service
    const mockServiceInstance = Service.init();
    expect(Service).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1)
  })
```

Comment: doesn't it break the idea that an instance have been already created inside the `./index.js` file itself ? I mean this line: `module.exports = new Statistics()`. It throws an error: `Service is not a constructor`

Comment: I think you can't check the class instance have you tried calling the init method explicitly? And Yes, you are right you don't need to make any new instance. Let me correct it.

Comment: I recommend you check the documentation [here](https://jestjs.io/docs/expect#tohavebeencalledtimesnumber).

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I was spying on a method after it was called.

This doesn't work:

```js
it('should ...', () => {
  instance = new MyClass();
  expect(jest.spyOn(instance, 'methodname')).toBeCalled();
});
```

But this does:

```js
it('should ...', () => {
  const f = jest.spyOn(instance, 'methodname');
  instance = new MyClass();
  expect(f).toBeCalled();
});
```